# Webscraping with a loop returns only a single element

Tags: python, web-scraping

When I run a for loop to collect elements within a `<div>` tag it only returns the first from a list of all with the same `class`.

For example:

```
r = requests.get("https://one-versus-one.com/en/rankings/all/statistics")

soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, 'lxml')

data = {
    'players': [],
    'club': [],
    'rank': []
}
def getstuff(soup):
    products = soup.find_all('div', {'class':'rankings-table'})
    for name in products:
        players = name.find('div', {'class':'player-name rankings-table__player-name'}).text
        club = name.find('span', {'class':'rankings-table__club-name'}).text
        rank = name.find('div', {'class':'rankings-table-cell value rankings-table__value'}).text.strip()
        data['players'] = players
        data['club'] = club
        data['rank'] = rank
        print(data)

getstuff(soup)
```

This returns:

> {'players': 'Lionel Messi', 'club': 'Barcelona', 'rank': '100'}

Where I expected all players, clubs and ranks to be printed within the page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try this:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

r = requests.get("https://one-versus-one.com/en/rankings/all/statistics")
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, 'lxml')

data = {'players': [],'club': [],'rank': []}

def getstuff(soup):
    products = soup.find('div', {'class':'rankings-table'}).find_all("a")
    for name in products:
        players = name.find('div', {'class':'player-name rankings-table__player-name'}).text
        club = name.find('span', {'class':'rankings-table__club-name'}).text
        rank = name.find('div', {'class':'rankings-table-cell value rankings-table__value'}).text.strip()
        data['players'].append(players)
        data['club'].append(club)
        data['rank'].append(rank)
    print(data)

getstuff(soup)
"""
{'players': ['Lionel Messi', 'Junior Neymar', 'Robert Lewandowski', 'Joao Cancelo', 'Kevin de Bruyne', 'Rodri', 'Jesse Lingard', 'Riyad Mahrez', 'Ilkay Gundogan', 'John Stones'], 'club': ['Barcelona', 'Paris Saint-Germain', 'Bayern Munich', 'Manchester City', 'Manchester City', 'Manchester City', 'West Ham United', 'Manchester City', 'Manchester City', 'Manchester City'], 'rank': ['100', '95', '93', '92', '91', '90', '90', '89', '88', '88']}
"""
```

You have to use `.find_all("a")` to get info about all players. And additional you're just making adding new player in `data['players']` insted of adding new player and for club, rank same.

Comment: How can I do this across all the pages? I have tried however the output only returns a single player like before, please have a look at my updated question.

Answer (score 1):

You are overwriting the variable within each loop rather than appending to a data set. Also, your products search only had one player within it.

Try

```
data = []


products = soup.select('a .rankings-table-row')
for name in products:
    players = name.find('div', {'class':'player-name rankings-table__player-name'}).text
    club = name.find('span', {'class':'rankings-table__club-name'}).text
    rank = name.find('div', {'class':'rankings-table-cell value rankings-table__value'}).text.strip()

    data.append(
        {
         'Players':  players,
         'Club': club,
         'Rank': rank
        }            
        )
data = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

Comment: What does: `a .rankings-table-row` represent? If I understand this correctly, the `a` is to select the tag, and the `.` means to selects all within `rankings-table-row`?

Comment: There are a few different ways you can 'select' items from a website (html tags, css selectors, xpath)

The one I have used above is a css selector. [Reference here](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp)

I swap between different types depending on the need and readability.

One super handy tool other than built in browser 'inspect' is 'SelectorGadget' which is a plugin on most browsers and worth a play with, the output from this is a css selector but can also provide an xpath.

Answer (score 0):

You should try

```
data['players'].append(players)
```

It's a list so appending should work. A list can be added to only by appending so if you do

```
data['players'] = players
```

it would assign the 'players' key to only a single value. Likewise for the other keys

The answer below me also mentions that you should use 'find_all'.

Comment: That only doesn't solves the OPs' all problem. I have gave the complete answer. You may check there.

Comment: Yes. I have also referenced your answer in the last line.

Answer (score 0):

I tried solving this too but with selenium. I even used an explicit wait : WebDriverWait, to make sure the element loads.

and still only Messi returns, none of the other players. The elements exist as entries but when trying to access their ".text" they return blank. Have people above tried their suggested solutions ?

Comment: Didn't check the others but mine worked. Did you change the `products` line to find all elements?

Comment: @Quixotic22 checked yours and another's . It works nicely with requests and Soup. But in selenium i could not even find elements i was "inspecting" on the home page. Anyway, problem is solved.