# Extract elements from multiple web-pages

Tags: python, web-scraping

I want to get information on football players for multiple web-pages however my code only returns a single player:

```
href=[]
for i in range(1, 10+1, 1):
    href.append("https://one-versus-one.com/en/rankings/all/statistics?page={}".format(i))


data = {'players': [],'club': [],'rank': []}

def getstuff(soup):
    for i in range(0, len(href), 1):
        r = requests.get(href[i])
        soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, 'lxml')
        products = soup.find('div', {'class':'rankings-table'}).find_all("a")
        for name in products:
            players = name.find('div', {'class':'player-name rankings-table__player-name'}).text
            club = name.find('span', {'class':'rankings-table__club-name'}).text
            rank = name.find('div', {'class':'rankings-table-cell value rankings-table__value'}).text.strip()
            data['players'].append(players)
            data['club'].append(club)
            data['rank'].append(rank)
            return(data)

players=getstuff(soup)
```

output:

```
    players             club    rank
0   Lionel Messi    Barcelona   100
```

Why does the `for-loop` not allow for all elements to iterate over each page?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Webscraping with a loop returns only a single element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68663773/webscraping-with-a-loop-returns-only-a-single-element)

Comment: @Carlo While that post helps it does not solve the question as I am trying to get it to work for multiple pages though I cannot understand why it does not work. If I remove `return(data)`, and instead use `print` it seems to grab everything

Answer (score 0, accepted):

there is an indentation error in your code.

You need to unindent `return data` to make your code work correctly. Currently the code returns the data instantly after the first for loop that only fetches the first row of data.

The updated function should look something like this:

```
def getstuff(soup):
    for i in range(0, len(href), 1):
        r = requests.get(href[i])
        soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, 'lxml')
        products = soup.find('div', {'class':'rankings-table'}).find_all("a")
        for name in products:
            players = name.find('div', {'class':'player-name rankings-table__player-name'}).text
            club = name.find('span', {'class':'rankings-table__club-name'}).text
            rank = name.find('div', {'class':'rankings-table-cell value rankings-table__value'}).text.strip()
            data['players'].append(players)
            data['club'].append(club)
            data['rank'].append(rank)
    return(data)
```

Comment: This does help although I still only get players for the first page and not for the rest

Comment: I have added a reference to the function, please check if that is working for you. It might be that you have only un-indented the return once

Comment: You are right! Thanks for that. However, it seems that the list of players are repeated twice for each page. Any idea what may be causing this issue here?

Comment: I am not able to replicate that, the function seems to be working as expected for me @Stackcans

Comment: I called the function twice which seems to append an extra 100 rows each time. It does produce the expected output - thanks